# The type or namespace name 'Imageformat' does not exist

Tags: image, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coding a MVC5 internet application and I am uploading images to Azure blob storage. When a user uploads an image, I wish to create a thumbnail image and save this image to blob storage as well.

I have the input stream of the image and am using this as the `Stream fileStream` parameter of my function.

Here is my current code:

```
public void CreateImageThumbnailFromStream(Stream fileStream, string filename, int width, int height)
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);
    System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);
    MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
    thumbnailImage.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.Imageformat.Jpeg);
    if (imageStream.Length > 0)
    {
        string containerName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        blob.UploadFromStream(imageStream);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Imageformat' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing.Imaging' (are you missing an assembly reference?
```

At this line of code:

```
thumbnailImage.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.Imageformat.Jpeg);
```

I have a reference to the following assembly:

```
System.Drawing (in System.Drawing.dll)
```

Here is the MSDN class documentation:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Can I please have some help with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

['ImageFormat'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat), not Imageformat, it is case-sensitive.